# How can I customize how the title is displayed?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I want to customize how the HTML for the title of my Dexterity content type is generated.

I wrote a view template for a the type that uses the metadata.IBasic behavior:

```xml
<html ...>
  <body>
    <metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
      <metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">
        <div id="conent-images">...</div>
        ...
        <div id="content-metadata">
          <h1 tal:content="context/title">Title</h1>
          ...
        </div>
        ...
        <div id="content-body">...</div>
      </metal:content-core>
    </metal:content-core>
  </body>
</html>
```

But Plone then renders the title twice. How can I remove the first apparition of title?

Comment: You only changed the element name between the snippets; they have no meaning. Did you mean to change the value in the `fill-slot` and `define-macro` attributes instead?

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake writing it here. I fixed it.

Comment: Why not just *omit* the title altogether? Something filling the `content-core` slot is already providing the title for you. :-)

Comment: Because I need to put the title in a box floating right with other attributes.

Comment: Right, that wasn't clear. To verify: You want to *customize* the Title display, not *add* it to your view.

Comment: Sorry if I have mistakes with English. I need to customize the title display to have at least 3 divs to describe products. The first having pictures. The second with the title and other attributes. And the last with a long description. So, I don't want having the title on the page top.

Comment: Understood now, I edited your question a little to make this clearer.

Comment: Now I understand how to solve my problem, so I'm working in to rewrite my question and in the answer to it.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer in that case! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn, your comments and answers always are useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code you are filling the slot named content-core. There are [several slots](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/how-to-write-templates-for-plone-4) defined in the layout that is the base for the template: `content-title`, `content-description` y `content-core`.

To remove the first title apparition you can fill the the `content-title` slot with nothing.

```xml
<html ...>
  <body>
    <metal:content-core fill-slot="content-title">
      <metal:content-core define-macro="content-title">
      </metal:conent-core>
    </metal:conent-core>
    <metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
      <metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">
        ...
        <h1 tal:content="context/title">Title</h1>
        ...
        <div id="content-body">...</div>
      </metal:content-core>
    </metal:content-core>
  </body>
</html>
```

Other solution is edit the template where slots are defined, but this solution is enough for me.